# Running to Form This Table Gives Error

Tags: tables, tabularx

I appreciate any helps on debugging this code below. I am having difficulty making this table (10-columns), where: arrays: (2:end,1)=3*multirow(3); Other arrays are normal.

Code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs, multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}
\newcommand{\otoprule}{\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]}

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\begin{document}
\title{Hi}
\maketitle
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle


\section{Introduction}



\begin{table}[hb]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{How To Tune it}
\label{tab:4}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}c >{$}c<{$} c c c c @{\hskip1.5em}S[table-format=1.4]S[table-format=2.1]@{}}
\toprule
    \thead{Step Change} & \thead{Type of}  & \thead{Active Power}        & \thead{Active Power}          & \thead{Active Power}         & \thead{Active Power}                                  &\thead{ $V_{DC}$ }    & \thead{ $V_{DC}$ }     & \thead{ $V_{DC}$ }    & \thead{ $V_{DC}$ }   \\


      \thead{Case}       &  \thead{Controller} & \thead{First Peak (P_{max})}  &  \thead{Steady-State (P_{ss})}  &  \thead{Overshoot (M_p) \%}  & \thead{Settling-    Time (t_s) $[sec]$}                  & \thead{First Peak (\mathit{V_{DC}^{max}})}  &  \thead{Steady-State ($\mathit{V_{DC}^{ss}}$)}  &  \thead{           Overshoot (M_p) \%}  & \thead{Settling-    Time (t_s) $[sec]$ }                   \\

\otoprule
\multirowcell{3}{$1$} &    \thead{Manual}    &   0.7880     &   0.4778    &    64.92   &    2.988   &   1.0591   &     1.0001    &    5.9    &    3.6128     \\
           & \thead{\SI{1}{}^{st} $ PI1$} &   0.6487        &   0.4779    &    35.74   &    0.368   &   1.0132   &     1.0000      &    1.32   &    0.3664s    \\
           & \thead{\SI{2}{}^{nd} $ PI2$} &   0.6489        &   0.4782    &    35.7    &    0.368   &   1.0132   &     1.0000      &    1.32   &      0.3664     \\                                 
\midrule
\multirowcell{3}{$2$} &    \thead{Manual}    &   0.0735     &   0.2295    &   -67.97   &    0.3248  &   0.9685   &     1.0000   &    -3.15   &    1.9600     \\
           & \thead{\SI{1}{}^{st} $ PI1$} &   0.0961        &   0.2295    &   -58.13     &    0.1200  &   0.9919   &       1.0000     &    -0.81   &      0.1984     \\
           & \thead{\SI{2}{}^{nd} $ PI2$} &   0.0932        &   0.2295      &   -59.39   &    0.1184  &   0.9917     &     1.0000     &    -0.83   &      0.1984     \\
\midrule
\multirowcell{3}{$3$} &    \thead{Manual}    &   1.0442     &  0.7331     &    42.44   &    3.7984  &   1.0617   &   1.0000     &     6.18    &   8.3168     \\
           & \thead{\SI{1}{}^{st} $ PI1$} &   0.9721        &  0.7319       &    32.82   &    0.5248  &   1.0165     &   1.0000     &     1.65    &   0.4144     \\
           & \thead{\SI{2}{}^{nd} $ PI2$} &   0.9725        &  0.7313       &    32.98   &    0.5200  &   1.0165   &     1.0000     &       1.65    &     0.4112     \\                                         

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

EDITED: what is the code to make it look alike below, where dir in the pic is same as Case No. here; and each "w" is similar to each 4 column here:

[image: Like This]

@Torbjørn T.:
Edited 2: I realized a problem. the margin (before tables) is very large considering the documentclass it should be produced in. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `S` columns you need to wrap the `\thead{...}` in a pair of braces, i.e. `{\thead{...}}`, to hide it from the parser. Then you need to add two more columns, as you haven't specified enough. This means the table becomes far too wide though, so you either have to make it a landscape table, or do something like in the code below, where an explanation of the column headings is added to the caption. (I didn't complete that though.)

To get the "headings" you describe in the edit, use a combination of `\multicolumn` and `\cmidrule`.

Also, it's still wider than one column, so I changed to `table*`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}
\newcommand{\otoprule}{\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]}

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\begin{document}
\author{Dude}
\title{Hi}
\maketitle
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{t}
\lipsum


\begin{table*}[hb]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{How To Tune it. $P_{max}$ is First Peak; $PP_{ss}$ is Steady-State; etc.}
\label{tab:4}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c *{2}{S[table-format=1.4]} S[table-format=-2.2] *{3}{S[table-format=1.4]} S[table-format=-1.2] S[table-format=1.4]}
\toprule

 & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Some text} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Some text} \\ \cmidrule(lr){3-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-10}
 \thead{Case} &  {\thead{Controller}} & {\thead{$P_{\mathrm{max}}$}}  &  {\thead{$P_{\mathrm{ss}}$}}  &  {\thead{$M_p$\%}}  & {\thead{$t_s$}}  & {\thead{$V_{\mathit{DC}}^{\mathrm{max}}$}}  &  {\thead{${V_{\mathit{DC}}^{\mathrm{ss}}}$}}  &  {\thead{$M_p$\%}}  & {\thead{$t_s$}} \\

\otoprule
$\text{case}=1$ \\ % I would rather say just Case 1, but that's up to you of course
           & \thead{Manual}    &   0.7880     &   0.4778    &    64.92   &    2.988   &   1.0591   &     1.0001    &    5.9    &    3.6128     \\
           & \thead{\num{1}\textsuperscript{st} PI1} &   0.6487     &   0.4779    &    35.74   &    0.368   &   1.0132   &     1.0000      &    1.32   &    0.3664s    \\
           & \thead{\num{2}\textsuperscript{nd} PI2} &   0.6489     &   0.4782    &    35.7    &    0.368   &   1.0132   &     1.0000      &    1.32   &      0.3664     \\                                 
%\midrule % there were no midrule in the picture 
$\text{case}=2$ \\
           & \thead{Manual}    &   0.0735     &   0.2295    &   -67.97   &    0.3248  &   0.9685   &     1.0000   &    -3.15   &    1.9600     \\
           & \thead{\num{1}\textsuperscript{st} PI1} &   0.0961     &   0.2295    &   -58.13     &    0.1200  &   0.9919   &       1.0000     &    -0.81   &      0.1984     \\
           & \thead{\num{2}\textsuperscript{nd} PI2} &   0.0932     &   0.2295      &   -59.39   &    0.1184  &   0.9917     &     1.0000     &    -0.83   &      0.1984     \\
%\midrule
$\text{case}=2$ \\
           & \thead{Manual}    &   1.0442     &  0.7331     &    42.44   &    3.7984  &   1.0617   &   1.0000     &     6.18    &   8.3168     \\
           & \thead{\num{1}\textsuperscript{st} PI1} &   0.9721     &  0.7319       &    32.82   &    0.5248  &   1.0165     &   1.0000     &     1.65    &   0.4144     \\
           & \thead{\num{2}\textsuperscript{nd} PI2} &   0.9725     &  0.7313       &    32.98   &    0.5200  &   1.0165   &     1.0000     &       1.65    &     0.4112     \\                                         

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Do you know how to make it alike the above table?

Comment: @Hans See above.

Comment: WoW, you're cool man. I just wonder if you could make it look alike the above pic with dir=1 eq. to case=1, .... relevant to my case?

Comment: @Hans Sorry, only noticed the new "heading". Changing the first column is just a matter of adding a new row, where the only thing in that row is the first cell, where it says case 1. I'll edit in a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just the last question: how to make the non-value rows/columns text bold-style in a professional looking context?

Comment: @Hans Same as you would make text bold in any other context I suppose. `\textbf{this is bold}`  The math I wouldn't make bold I think.

Comment: I couldn't make those `\mathit` in it alike Pmax, ... bold using above. By the way could you pls help me with this: [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271463/having-three-sequential-tables-next-to-each-other-2-side-by-side-and-3rd-below)

Comment: @Hans As I said, I wouldn't make the math parts bold, `$\bm{A}$` (`\bm{..}` requires `\usepackage{bm}`) is not the same symbol as `$A$`. That said, you can also use `\mathbf{A}`, but note that that will be bold upright, not bold italic. `\bm{A}` will be bold italic.

Comment: Could you pls see the above Edited 2 in main question.

Comment: @Hans Please make a new question about that, it's a completely separate problem.

Comment: But its the same code you had uploaded. When you run it, it produces a large margin from where it should start. should I use `\vspace` or maybe there is an authentic answer to fix this?

Comment: @Hans Sure, but I don't know the answer. So ask a new question, that way other people will see it, and there's a better chance of you getting a reply. Good night.

Comment: @Hans That said, if you add enough text before and after the table it will likely look better.