# Having Three Sequential Tables Next to each other (2 side-by-side and 3rd below them)

Tags: tables, floats

How can I put the first two tables side by side and then add the 3rd table below them in IEEEtrans style document class and at the top/bottom of the page by modifying code below? (I don't want any other manuscript text go in between them) Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs, multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}
\newcommand{\otoprule}{\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]}

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\begin{document}
\title{Hi}
\maketitle
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle


\section{Introduction}

\begin{table*}[tp]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{x}
\label{tab:2}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}c >{$}c<{$}@{\hskip1.5em}S[table-format=1.4]S[table-format=2.1]@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{VSI Controller\\Parameters}} & {\thead{Minimum\\Value}} & {\thead{Maximum\\Value}} \\
\otoprule
\multirowcell{4}{Outer Control \\ Loops} & k_{p_1} & 0.002 & 5 \\
                               & T_{i_1} & 0.0001 & 0.5 \\
                               & k_{p_2} & 0.01 & 3 \\
                               & T_{i_2} & 0.0001 & 0.5 \\
\midrule
\multirowcell{4}{Inner Control \\ Loop} & k_{p_3} & 0.1 &  15  \verb+  + \\
                               & T_{i_3} & 0.001 & 0.5 \\
                               & k_{p_4} & 0.1 &  10  \verb+  + \\
                               & T_{i_4} & 0.001 & 0.5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Results }
\label{tab:3}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{$}c {$}c< {$}c<{$}lc@{\hskip1.5em}S[table-format=1.4]S[table-format=2.1]@{}}
\toprule
\thead{Controller}   &  \thead{{Initial }}  &  \thead{\SI{1}{}^{st} $ PI$} &    \thead{\SI{2}{}^{nd} $PI2}$ }\\
\thead{Parameters}        &    \thead{fd}    &         \thead{Tuning}          &           \thead{Tuning}        \\  
    \otoprule

$k_{p_1}$         &\SI{2}{}            &   \SI{3.5467}{}                  &   \SI{3.5467}{}\\

$ T_{i_1}$         &\SI{0.02}{}         &   \SI{0.0014}{}                &   \SI{0.0014}{}\\

    $k_{p_2}$         &\SI{1}{}            &   \SI{1.9389}{}                &   \SI{1.9389}{}\\

    $T_{i_2}$         &\SI{0.05}{}            &   \SI{0.1846}{}                &   \SI{0.1846}{}\\

    $k_{p_3}$         &\SI{10}{}            &   \SI{10}{}                &   \SI{9.0243}{}\\

    $T_{i_3}$         &\SI{0.05}{}            &   \SI{0.05}{}                &   \SI{0.2975}{}\\

    $k_{p_4} $        &\SI{3.4}{}            &   \SI{3.4}{}                &   \SI{3.8011}{}\\

    $T_{i_4} $        &\SI{0.05}{}            &   \SI{0.05}{}                &   \SI{0.0650}{}\\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{How To Tune it. $P_{max}$ is First Peak; $PP_{ss}$ is Steady-State; etc.}
\label{tab:4}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c *{2}{S[table-format=1.4]} S[table-format=-2.2] *{3}{S[table-format=1.4]} S[table-format=-1.2] S[table-format=1.4]}
\toprule

 & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Some text} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Some text} \\ \cmidrule(lr){3-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-10}
 \thead{Case} &  {\thead{Controller}} & {\thead{$P_{\mathrm{max}}$}}  &  {\thead{$P_{\mathrm{ss}}$}}  &  {\thead{$M_p$\%}}  & {\thead{$t_s$}}  & {\thead{$V_{\mathit{DC}}^{\mathrm{max}}$}}  &  {\thead{${V_{\mathit{DC}}^{\mathrm{ss}}}$}}  &  {\thead{$M_p$\%}}  & {\thead{$t_s$}} \\

\otoprule
$\text{case}=1$ \\ % I would rather say just Case 1, but that's up to you of course
       & \thead{Manual}    &   0.7880     &   0.4778    &    64.92   &    2.988   &   1.0591   &     1.0001    &    5.9    &    3.6128     \\
       & \thead{\num{1}\textsuperscript{st} PI1} &   0.6487     &   0.4779    &    35.74   &    0.368   &   1.0132   &     1.0000      &    1.32   &    0.3664s    \\
       & \thead{\num{2}\textsuperscript{nd} PI2} &   0.6489     &   0.4782    &    35.7    &    0.368   &   1.0132   &     1.0000      &    1.32   &      0.3664     \\                                 
%\midrule % there were no midrule in the picture 
$\text{case}=2$ \\
       & \thead{Manual}    &   0.0735     &   0.2295    &   -67.97   &    0.3248  &   0.9685   &     1.0000   &    -3.15   &    1.9600     \\
       & \thead{\num{1}\textsuperscript{st} PI1} &   0.0961     &   0.2295    &   -58.13     &    0.1200  &   0.9919   &       1.0000     &    -0.81   &      0.1984     \\
       & \thead{\num{2}\textsuperscript{nd} PI2} &   0.0932     &   0.2295      &   -59.39   &    0.1184  &   0.9917     &     1.0000     &    -0.83   &      0.1984     \\
%\midrule
$\text{case}=2$ \\
       & \thead{Manual}    &   1.0442     &  0.7331     &    42.44   &    3.7984  &   1.0617   &   1.0000     &     6.18    &   8.3168     \\
       & \thead{\num{1}\textsuperscript{st} PI1} &   0.9721     &  0.7319       &    32.82   &    0.5248  &   1.0165     &   1.0000     &     1.65    &   0.4144     \\
       & \thead{\num{2}\textsuperscript{nd} PI2} &   0.9725     &  0.7313       &    32.98   &    0.5200  &   1.0165   &     1.0000     &       1.65    &     0.4112     \\                                         

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Edit: @Torbjørn T. But, it is running without error on TeXnicCenter.

Comment: Always a good idea to test that the example compiles before posting - yours throw an error.

Comment: That said, put the first two tables and their respective captions in two `minipage` environments (one per table) as in [How can I have two tables side by side?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88054), and the third table after the minipages.

Comment: It's not running without errors here. TeXnicCenter is probably running it in `nonstopmode`, meaning that TeX skips past errors and tries to make a PDF anyway. Isn't there some panel listing warnings and errors in TXC?

Comment: You are right. TexnicCenter bypasses the minor errors and gives me final result correctly. Could you pls kindly fix it, I donno what to do and I need to submit ASAP :(

Comment: The error: Package array error: Illeagal pream-token ($): 'c' used.

Comment: That and others. Don't use `\SI{2}{}` for numbers. Because I'm occasionally nice: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/torbjornt/pLkB8

Comment: @Mico Hans wrote the question. Hans: did you click the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for your kindness. It is working, how can I credit you here :-)

Comment: Nah, don't worry about that. As for this question, I'll vote to close as duplicate of the one I mentioned above.